# DXGrid binding not showing cell value

Tags: wpf, devexpress, mvvm-light

I am updating my project to use the DevExpress DXGrid.
note: I am using he MVVM light toolkit.

I was successfully binding to the default wpf grid, but now i want to ramp it up to use DXgrid.
I "think" i am binding correctly, but when the grid displays the cells are all empty. the row number is correct (i.e. i have 3 cars, i get 3 rows) so it is definitely seeing my data, but i am sure i am missing a property somewhere becaus enone of the text displays all the cells are empty

```
        <dxg:GridControl.Columns>

            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="{Binding Path=Id}" Header="ID"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="{Binding Path=NominationDate, StringFormat=\{0:dd/MM/yyyy\}}" Header="Nomination Date" />
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="{Binding Path=CarNumber}" Header="CarNumber"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="{Binding Path=CarName}" Header="Car Name" />
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="{Binding Path=Colour}" Header="Colour"/>


        </dxg:GridControl.Columns>

        <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:TableView Name="tableView1" SelectedRowsSource="{Binding Selection}" MultiSelectMode="Row" NavigationStyle="Row"  />


        </dxg:GridControl.View>
    </dxg:GridControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try prefixing your properties with RowData or Data. these are dependency objects exposed by dxgrid for retreival of the bound data.  so in your case you would have something like below..

```
 <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="{Binding RowData.Path=Id}" Header="ID"/>

or 

 <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="{Binding Data.Path=Id}" Header="ID"/>
```

Comment: ah...sorry i might have been thinking the wrong thing.  try just the field name without binding (i.e. FieldName="Id")..at least that's how i recall using dxgrid.  (RowData is for retrieval of the bound data in templates)..  Also what kind of data structure are you binding to?  ObservableCollection?

Comment: i think i cracked it - i need to set DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Id}"

Answer (score 0):

i need to set DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Id}"

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
        <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Id" Header="ID"/>
        <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="NominationDate" Header="Nomination Date"/>
        <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="CarNumber" Header="CarNumber"/>
        <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="CarName" Header="Car Name" />
        <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Colour" Header="Colour"/>

    </dxg:GridControl.Columns>

    <dxg:GridControl.View>
        <dxg:TableView Name="tableView1" SelectedRowsSource="{Binding Selection}" MultiSelectMode="Row" NavigationStyle="Row"  />


    </dxg:GridControl.View>
</dxg:GridControl>
```